# Adobe Connect 9 API - Set Recording Passcode

Tags: api, adobe, adobe-connect

I'm trying set the passcode to a Recording. The API respondes with Ok message, but the Recording still without the passcode.

I tried the permissions-update in the recording to set public:

http://server_name/api/xml?action=permissions-update&acl-id=123456789&principal-id=public-access&permission-id=view&session=cookieFromAnAdminUserLogged

After set the permission I tried set the passcode using the acl-field-update like this:

http://server_name.com/api/xml?action=acl-field-update&acl-id=123456789&field-id=meeting-passcode&value=aBea12Ce&session=cookieFromAnAdminUserLogged

In the Adobe Connect Admin Panel the permission is Public, but the passcode is not set.

This way I set the passcode for Meetings, but for Recordings is not working. I tried change the field-id to recording-passcode, but the API response is an error.

Anyone knows set the passcode to Recording?

---

Update:

Thanks to Jorma_at_RealEyes in the Adobe Connect User Community Forum I find this call and works fine:

```
https://server_name.com/api/xml?
    action=acl-field-update
    &acl-id=123456789
    &field-id=meeting-passcode
    &value=password
    &is-mtg-passcode-req=true
    &permission-id=view-only
    &principal-id=public-access
    &session=cookieFromAnAdminUserLogged
```

But before is necessary set the permission to public.